# How to find the exact version of D3 given the minified file?

Tags: git, d3.js

I work with a legacy system that uses a lot of D3. Unfortunately, the person who committed our minified d3.js to the repo years ago didn't document which version it was, so now I'm trying to find exactly which version it is so I can get it to play nice with webpack and also assess what would need to happen to be able to upgrade D3.

What is the best way to find the version of D3 we have, given this info?

The commit was on 2013-09-05 and the file itself has shasum `8c20d53ba2c073a0b939b06847f12204ba0f81c6`. I checked 3.3.[0-3] in the [releases here](https://github.com/d3/d3/releases?after=v3.3.8) by doing a diff with my file, but didn't find it.

I also made a little bash script to find it, but couldn't locate it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for tag in $(  git tag -l | grep -e "v2.8.*" -e "v2.9.*" -e "v3.0.*" ); do
    echo -e "\n"
    git checkout $tag > /dev/null;
    for jsfile in *.js; do
      sha=$(shasum $jsfile | awk "{print $1}")
      if [[ "$sha" == "8c20d53ba2c073a0b939b06847f12204ba0f81c6" ]]; then
        echo "Found it! $tag has file $jsfile with the right sha!"
      fi
    done
done
```

This is part of the first line:

```
d3=function(){function n(n){return null!=n&&!isNaN(n)}function t(n){return n.length}function e(n){for(var t=1;n*t%1;)t*=10;return t}function r(n,t){try{for(var e in t)Object.defineProperty(n.prototype,e,{value:t[e],enumerable:!1})}catch(r){n.prototype=t}}function i(){}function u(){}function a(n,t,e){return function(){var r=e.apply(t,arguments);return r===t?n:r}}function o(n,t){if(t in n)return t;t=t.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+t.substring(1);for(var e=0,r=Ca.length;r>e;++e){var i=Ca[e]+t;if(i in n)return i}}function c(n){for(var t=n.length,e=new Array(t);t--;)e[t]=n[t];return e}function l(n){return Array.prototype.slice.call(n)}function s(){}function f(){}function h(n){function t(){for(var t,r=e,i=-1,u=r.length;++i<u;)(t=r[i].on)&&t.apply(this,arguments);return n}var e=[],r=new i;return t.on=function(t,i){var u,a=r.get(t);return arguments.length<2?a&&a.on:(a&&(a.on=null,e=e.slice(0,u=e.indexOf(a)).concat(e.slice(u+1)),r.remove(t)),i&&e.push(r.set(t,{on:i})),n)},t}function g(){ya.event.preventDefault()}function p(){for(var n,t=ya.event;n=t.sourceEvent;)t=n;return t}function m(n){for(var t=new f,e=0,r=arguments.length;++e<r;)t[arguments[e]]=h(t);return t.of=function(e,r){return function(i){try{var u=i.sourceEvent=ya.event;i.target=n,ya.event=i,t[i.type].apply(e,r)}finally{ya.event=u}}},t}function d(n){return La(n,Ya),n}function v(n){return"function"==typeof n?n:function(){return Ha(n,this)}}function y(n){return"function"==typeof n?n:function(){return Fa(n,this)}}function M(n,t){function e(){this.removeAttribute(n)}function r(){this.removeAttributeNS(n.space,n.local)}function i(){this.setAttribute(n,t)}function u(){this.setAttributeNS(n.space,n.local,t)}function a(){var e=t.apply(this,arguments);null==e?this.removeAttribute(n):this.setAttribute(n,e)}function o(){var e=t.apply(this,arguments);null==e?this.removeAttributeNS(n.space,n.local):this.setAttributeNS(n.space,n.local,e)}return n=ya.ns.qualify(n),null==t?n.local?r:e:"function"==typeof t?n.local?o:a:n.local?u:i}function x(n){return n.trim().replace(/\s+/g," ")}function b(n){return new RegExp("(?:^|\\s+)"+ya.requote(n)+"(?:\\s+|$)","g")}function _(n,t){function e(){for(var e=-1;++e<i;)n[e](this,t)}function r(){for(var e=-1,r=t.apply(this,arguments);++e<i;)n[e](this,r)}n=n.trim().split(/\s+/).map(w);var i=n.length;return"function"==typeof t?r:e}function w(n){var t=b(n);return function(e,r){if(i=e.classList)return r?i.add(n):i.remove(n);var i=e.getAttribute("class")||"";r?(t.lastIndex=0,t.test(i)||e.setAttribute("class",x(i+" "+n))):e.setAttribute("class",x(i.replace(t," ")))}}function S(n,t,e){function r(){this.style.removeProperty(n)}function i(){this.style.setProperty(n,t,e)}function u(){var r=t.apply(this,arguments);null==r?this.style.removeProperty(n):this.style.setProperty(n,r,e)}return null==t?r:"function"==typeof t?u:i}function E(n,t){function e(){delete this[n]}function r(){this[n]=t}function i(){var e=t.apply(this,arguments);null==e?delete this[n]:this[n]=e}return null==t?e:"function"==typeof t?i:r}function k(n){return"function"==typeof n?n:(n=ya.ns.qualify(n)).local?function(){return Ma.createElementNS(n.space,n.local)}:function(){return Ma.createElementNS(this.namespaceURI,n)}}function A(n){return{__data__:n}}function N(n){return function(){return Oa(this,n)}}function q(n){return arguments.length||(n=ya.ascending),function(t,e){return t&&e?n(t.__data__,e.__data__):!t-!e}}function T(n,t){for(var e=0,r=n.length;r>e;e++)for(var i,u=n[e],a=0,o=u.length;o>a;a++)(i=u[a])&&t(i,a,e);return n}function C(n){return La(n,Ua),n}function z(n){var t,e;return function(r,i,u){var a,o=n[u].update,c=o.length;for(u!=e&&(e=u,t=0),i>=t&&(t=i+1);!(a=o[t])&&++t<c;);return a}}function D(n,t,e){function r(){var t=this[a];t&&(this.removeEventListener(n,t,t.$),delete this[a])}function i(){var i=c(t,za(arguments));r.call(this),this.addEventListener(n,this[a]=i,i.$=e),i._=t}function u(){var t,e=new RegExp("^__on([^.]+)"+ya.requote(n)+"$");for(var r in this)if(t=r.match(e)){var i=this[r];this.removeEventListener(t[1],i,i.$),delete this[r]}}var a="__on"+n,o=n.indexOf("."),c=j;o>0&&(n=n.substring(0,o));var l=Va.get(n);return l&&(n=l,c=L),o?t?i:r:t?s:u}function j(n,t){return function(e){var r=ya.event;ya.event=e,t[0]=this.__data__;try{n.apply(this,t)}finally{ya.event=r}}}function L(n,t){var e=j(n,t);return function(n){var t=this,r=n.relatedTarget;r&&(r===t||8&r.compareDocumentPosition(t))||e.call(t,n)}}function H(){var n=".dragsuppress-"+ ++Za,t="touchmove"+n,e="selectstart"+n,r="dragstart"+n,i="click"+n,u=ya.select(ba).on(t,g).on(e,g).on(r,g),a=xa.style,o=a[Xa];return a[Xa]="none",function(t){function e(){u.on(i,null)}u.on(n,null),a[Xa]=o,t&&(u.on(i,function(){g(),e()},!0),setTimeout(e,0))}}function F(n,t){var e=n.ownerSVGElement||n;if(e.createSVGPoint){var r=e.createSVGPoint();if(0>Ba&&(ba.scrollX||ba.scrollY)){e=ya.select("body").append("svg").style({position:"absolute",top:0,left:0,margin:0,padding:0,border:"none"},"important");var i=e[0][0].getScreenCTM();Ba=!(i.f||i.e),e.remove()}return Ba?(r.x=t.pageX,r.y=t.pageY):(r.x=t.clientX,r.y=t.clientY),r=r.matrixTransform(n.getScreenCTM().inverse()),[r.x,r.y]}var u=n.getBoundingClientRect();return[t.clientX-u.left-n.clientLeft,t.clientY-u.top-n.clientTop]}function P(){}function O(n,t,e){return new Y(n,t,e)}function Y(n,t,e){this.h=n,this.s=t,this.l=e}function R(n,t,e){function r(n){return n>360?n-=360:0>n&&(n+=360),60>n?u+(a-u)*n/60:180>n?a:240>n?u+(a-u)*(240-n)/60:u}function i(n){return Math.round(255*r(n))}var u,a;return n=isNaN(n)?0:(n%=360)<0?n+360:n,t=isNaN(t)?0:0>t?0:t>1?1:t,e=0>e?0:e>1?1:e,a=.5>=e?e*(1+t):e+t-e*t,u=2*e-a,at(i(n+120),i(n),i(n-120))}function U(n){return n>0?1:0>n?-1:0}function I(n){return n>1?0:-1>n?Ka:Math.acos(n)}function V(n){return n>1?Ka/2:-1>n?-Ka/2:Math.asin(n)}function X(n){return(Math.exp(n)-Math.exp(-n))/2}function Z(n){return(Math.exp(n)+Math.exp(-n))/2}function B(n){return(n=Math.sin(n/2))*n}function $(n,t,e){return new W(n,t,e)}function W(n,t,e){this.h=n,this.c=t,this.l=e}function J(n,t,e){return isNaN(n)&&(n=0),isNaN(t)&&(t=0),G(e,Math.cos(n*=to)*t,Math.sin(n)*t)}function G(n,t,e){return new K(n,t,e)}function K(n,t,e){this.l=n,this.a=t,this.b=e}function Q(n,t,e){var r=(n+16)/116,i=r+t/500,u=r-e/200;return i=tt(i)*uo,r=tt(r)*ao,u=tt(u)*oo,at(rt(3.2404542*i-1.5371385*r-.4985314*u),rt(-.969266*i+1.8760108*r+.041556*u),rt(.0556434*i-.2040259*r+1.0572252*u))}function nt(n,t,e){return n>0?$(Math.atan2(e,t)*eo,Math.sqrt(t*t+e*e),n):$(0/0,0/0,n)}function tt(n){return n>.206893034?n*n*n:(n-4/29)/7.787037}function et(n){return n>.008856?Math.pow(n,1/3):7.787037*n+4/29}function rt(n){return Math.round(255*(.00304>=n?12.92*n:1.055*Math.pow(n,1/2.4)-.055))}function it(n){return at(n>>16,255&n>>8,255&n)}function ut(n){return it(n)+""}function at(n,t,e){return new ot(n,t,e)}function ot(n,t,e){this.r=n,this.g=t,this.b=e}function ct(n){return 16>n?"0"+Math.max(0,n).toString(16):Math.min(255,n).toString(16)}function lt(n,t,e){var r,i,u,a=0,o=0,c=0;if(r=/([a-z]+)\((.*)\)/i.exec(n))switch(i=r[2].split(","),r[1]){case"hsl":return e(parseFloat(i[0]),parseFloat(i[1])/100,parseFloat(i[2])/100);case"rgb":return t(gt(i[0]),gt(i[1]),gt(i[2]))}return(u=so.get(n))?t(u.r,u.g,u.b):(null!=n&&"#"===n.charAt(0)&&(4===n.length?(a=n.charAt(1),a+=a,o=n.charAt(2),o+=o,c=n.charAt(3),c+=c):7===n.length&&(a=n.substring(1,3),o=n.substring(3,5),c=n.substring(5,7)),a=parseInt(a,16),o=parseInt(o,16),c=parseInt(c,16)),t(a,o,c))}function st(n,t,e){var r,i,u=Math.min(n/=255,t/=255,e/=255),a=Math.max(n,t,e),o=a-u,c=(a+u)/2;return o?(i=.5>c?o/(a+u):o/(2-a-u),r=n==a?(t-e)/o+(e>t?6:0):t==a?(e-n)/o+2:(n-t)/o+4,r*=60):(r=0/0,i=c>0&&1>c?0:r),O(r,i,c)}function ft(n,t,e){n=ht(n),t=ht(t),e=ht(e);var r=et((.4124564*n+.3575761*t+.1804375*e)/uo),i=et((.2126729*n+.7151522*t+.072175*e)/ao),u=et((.0193339*n+.119192*t+.9503041*e)/oo);return G(116*i-16,500*(r-i),200*(i-u))}function ht(n){return(n/=255)<=.04045?n/12.92:Math.pow((n+.055)/1.055,2.4)}function gt(n){var t=parseFloat(n);return"%"===n.charAt(n.length-1)?Math.round(2.55*t):t}function pt(n){return"function"==typeof n?n:function(){return n}}function mt(n){return n}function dt(n){return function(t,e,r){return 2===arguments.length&&"function"==typeof e&&(r=e,e=null),vt(t,e,n,r)}}function vt(n,t,e,r){function i(){var n,t=c.status;if(!t&&c.responseText||t>=200&&300>t||304===t){try{n=e.call(u,c)}catch(r){return a.error.call(u,r),void 0}a.load.call(u,n)}else a.error.call(u,c)}var u={},a=ya.dispatch("progress","load","error"),o={},c=new XMLHttpRequest,l=null;return!ba.XDomainRequest||"withCredentials"in c||!/^(http(s)?:)?\/\//.test(n)||(c=new XDomainRequest),"onload"in c?c.onload=c.onerror=i:c.onreadystatechange=function(){c.readyState>3&&i()},c.onprogress=function(n){var t=ya.event;ya.event=n;try{a.progress.call(u,c)}finally{ya.event=t}},u.header=function(n,t){return n=(n+"").toLowerCase(),arguments.length<2?o[n]:(null==t?delete o[n]:o[n]=t+"",u)},u.mimeType=function(n){return arguments.length?(t=null==n?null:n+"",u):t},u.responseType=function(n){return arguments.length?(l=n,u):l},u.response=function(n){return e=n,u},["get","post"].forEach(function(n){u[n]=function(){return u.send.apply(u,[n].concat(za(arguments)))}}),u.send=function(e,r,i){if(2===arguments.length&&"function"==typeof r&&(i=r,r=null),c.open(e,n,!0),null==t||"accept"in o||(o.accept=t+",*/*"),c.setRequestHeader)for(var a in o)c.setRequestHeader(a,o[a]);return null!=t&&c.overrideMimeType&&c.overrideMimeType(t),null!=l&&(c.responseType=l),null!=i&&u.on("error",i).on("load",function(n){i(null,n)}),c.send(null==r?null:r),u},u.abort=function(){return c.abort(),u},ya.rebind(u,a,"on"),null==r?u:u.get(yt(r))}function yt(n){return 1===n.length?function(t,e){n(null==t?e:null)}:n}function Mt(){var n=bt(),t=_t()-n;t>24?(isFinite(t)&&(clearTimeout(po),po=setTimeout(Mt,t)),go=0):(go=1,vo(Mt))}function xt(n,t,e){var r=arguments.length;2>r&&(t=0),3>r&&(e=Date.now()),mo.callback=n,mo.time=e+t}function bt(){var n=Date.now();for(mo=fo;mo;)n>=mo.time&&(mo.flush=mo.callback(n-mo.time)),mo=mo.next;return n}function _t(){for(var n,t=fo,e=1/0;t;)t.flush?t=n?n.next=t.next:fo=t.next:(t.time<e&&(e=t.time),t=(n=t).next);return ho=n,e}function wt(n,t){var e=Math.pow(10,3*Math.abs(8-t));return{scale:t>8?function(n){return n/e}:function(n){return n*e},symbol:n}}function St(n,t){return t-(n?Math.ceil(Math.log(n)/Math.LN10):1)}function Et(n){return n+""}function kt(){}function At(n,t,e){var r=e.s=n+t,i=r-n,u=r-i;e.t=n-u+(t-i)}function Nt(n,t){n&&qo.hasOwnProperty(n.type)&&qo[n.type](n,t)}function qt(n,t,e){var r,i=-1,u=n.length-e;for(t.lineStart();++i<u;)r=n[i],t.point(r[0],r[1]);t.lineEnd()}function Tt(n,t){var e=-1,r=n.length;for(t.polygonStart();++e<r;)qt(n[e],t,1);t.polygonEnd()}function Ct(){function n(n,t){n*=to,t=t*to/2+Ka/4;var e=n-r,a=Math.cos(t),o=Math.sin(t),c=u*o,l=i*a+c*Math.cos(e),s=c*Math.sin(e);Co.add(Math.atan2(s,l)),r=n,i=a,u=o}var t,e,r,i,u;zo.point=function(a,o){zo.point=n,r=(t=a)*to,i=Math.cos(o=(e=o)*to/2+Ka/4),u=Math.sin(o)},zo.lineEnd=function(){n(t,e)}}function zt(n){var t=n[0],e=n[1],r=Math.cos(e);return[r*Math.cos(t),r*Math.sin(t),Math.sin(e)]}function Dt(n,t){return n[0]*t[0]+n[1]*t[1]+n[2]*t[2]}function jt(n,t){return[n[1]*t[2]-n[2]*t[1],n[2]*t[0]-n[0]*t[2],n[0]*t[1]-n[1]*t[0]]}function Lt(n,t){n[0]+=t[0],n[1]+=t[1],n[2]+=t[2]}function Ht(n,t){return[n[0]*t,n[1]*t,n[2]*t]}function Ft(n){var t=Math.sqrt(n[0]*n[0]+n[1]*n[1]+n[2]*n[2]);n[0]/=t,n[1]/=t,n[2]/=t}function Pt(n){return[Math.atan2(n[1],n[0]),V(n[2])]}function Ot(n,t){return Math.abs(n[0]-t[0])<Qa&&Math.abs(n[1]-t[1])<Qa}function Yt(n,t){n*=to;var e=Math.cos(t*=to);Rt(e*Math.cos(n),e*Math.sin(n),Math.sin(t))}function Rt(n,t,e){++Do,Lo+=(n-Lo)/Do,Ho+=(t-Ho)/Do,Fo+=(e-Fo)/Do}function Ut(){function n(n,i){n*=to;var u=Math.cos(i*=to),a=u*Math.cos(n),o=u*Math.sin(n),c=Math.sin(i),l=Math.atan2(Math.sqrt((l=e*c-r*o)*l+(l=r*a-t*c)*l+(l=t*o-e*a)*l),t*a+e*o+r*c);jo+=l,Po+=l*(t+(t=a)),Oo+=l*(e+(e=o)),Yo+=l*(r+(r=c)),Rt(t,e,r)}var t,e,r;Vo.point=function(i,u){i*=to;var a=Math.cos(u*=to);t=a*Math.cos(i),e=a*Math.sin(i),r=Math.sin(u),Vo.point=n,Rt(t,e,r)}}function It(){Vo.point=Yt}function Vt(){function n(n,t){n*=to;var e=Math.cos(t*=to),a=e*Math.cos(n),o=e*Math.sin(n),c=Math.sin(t),l=i*c-u*o,s=u*a-r*c,f=r*o-i*a,h=Math.sqrt(l*l+s*s+f*f),g=r*a+i*o+u*c,p=h&&-I(g)/h,m=Math.atan2(h,g);Ro+=p*l,Uo+=p*s,Io+=p*f,jo+=m,Po+=m*(r+(r=a)),Oo+=m*(i+(i=o)),Yo+=m*(u+(u=c)),Rt(r,i,u)}var t,e,r,i,u;Vo.point=function(a,o){t=a,e=o,Vo.point=n,a*=to;var c=Math.cos(o*=to);r=c*Math.cos(a),i=c*Math.sin(a),u=Math.sin(o),Rt(r,i,u)},Vo.lineEnd=function(){n(t,e),Vo.lineEnd=It,Vo.point=Yt}}function Xt(){return!0}function Zt(n,t,e,r,i){var u=[],a=[];if(n.forEach(function(n){if(!((t=n.length-1)<=0)){var t,e=n[0],r=n[t];if(Ot(e,r)){i.lineStart();for(var o=0;t>o;++o)i.point((e=n[o])[0],e[1]);return i.lineEnd(),void 0}var c={point:e,points:n,other:null,visited:!1,entry:!0,subject:!0},l={point:e,points:[e],other:c,visited:!1,entry:!1,subject:!1};c.other=l,u.push(c),a.push(l),c={point:r,points:[r],other:null,visited:!1,entry:!1,subject:!0},l={point:r,points:[r],other:c,visited:!1,entry:!0,subject:!1},c.other=l,u.push(c),a.push(l)}}),a.sort(t),Bt(u),Bt(a),u.length){if(e)for(var o=1,c=!e(a[0].point),l=a.length;l>o;++o)a[o].entry=c=!c;for(var s,f,h,g=u[0];;){for(s=g;s.visited;)if((s=s.next)===g)return;f=s.points,i.lineStart();do{if(s.visited=s.other.visited=!0,s.entry){if(s.subject)for(var o=0;o<f.length;o++)i.point((h=f[o])[0],h[1]);else r(s.point,s.next.point,1,i);s=s.next}else{if(s.subject){f=s.prev.points;for(var o=f.length;--o>=0;)i.point((h=f[o])[0],h[1])}else r(s.point,s.prev.point,-1,i);s=s.prev}s=s.other,f=s.points}while(!s.visited);i.lineEnd()}}}function Bt(n){if(t=n.length){for(var t,e,r=0,i=n[0];++r<t;)i.next=e=n[r],e.prev=i,i=e;i.next=e=n[0],e.prev=i}}function $t(n,t,e,r){return function(i){function u(t,e){n(t,e)&&i.point(t,e)}function a(n,t){m.point(n,t)}function o(){d.point=a,m.lineStart()}function c(){d.point=u,m.lineEnd()}function l(n,t){y.point(n,t),p.push([n,t])}function s(){y.lineStart(),p=[]}function f(){l(p[0][0],p[0][1]),y.lineEnd();var n,t=y.clean(),e=v.buffer(),r=e.length;if(p.pop(),g.push(p),p=null,r){if(1&t){n=e[0];var u,r=n.length-1,a=-1;for(i.lineStart();++a<r;)i.point((u=n[a])[0],u[1]);return i.lineEnd(),void 0}r>1&&2&t&&e.push(e.pop().concat(e.shift())),h.push(e.filter(Wt))}}var h,g,p,m=t(i),d={point:u,lineStart:o,lineEnd:c,polygonStart:function(){d.point=l,d.lineStart=s,d.lineEnd=f,h=[],g=[],i.polygonStart()},polygonEnd:function(){d.point=u,d.lineStart=o,d.lineEnd=c,h=ya.merge(h),h.length?Zt(h,Gt,null,e,i):r(g)&&(i.lineStart(),e(null,null,1,i),i.lineEnd()),i.polygonEnd(),h=g=null},sphere:function(){i.polygonStart(),i.lineStart(),e(null,null,1,i),i.lineEnd(),i.polygonEnd()}},v=Jt(),y=t(v);return d}}function Wt(n){return n.length>1}function Jt(){var n,t=[];return{lineStart:function(){t.push(n=[])},point:function(t,e){n.push([t,e])},lineEnd:s,buffer:function(){var e=t;return t=[],n=null,e},rejoin:function(){t.length>1&&t.push(t.pop().concat(t.shift()))}}}function Gt(n,t){return((n=n.point)[0]<0?n[1]-Ka/2-Qa:Ka/2-n[1])-((t=t.point)[0]<0?t[1]-Ka/2-Qa:Ka/2-t[1])}function Kt(n,t){var e=n[0],r=n[1],i=[Math.sin(e),-Math.cos(e),0],u=0,a=!1,o=!1,c=0;Co.reset();for(var l=0,s=t.length;s>l;++l){var f=t[l],h=f.length;if(h){for(var g=f[0],p=g[0],m=g[1]/2+Ka/4,d=Math.sin(m),v=Math.cos(m),y=1;;){y===h&&(y=0),n=f[y];var M=n[0],x=n[1]/2+Ka/4,b=Math.sin(x),_=Math.cos(x),w=M-p,S=Math.abs(w)>Ka,E=d*b;if(Co.add(Math.atan2(E*Math.sin(w),v*_+E*Math.cos(w))),Math.abs(x)<Qa&&(o=!0),u+=S?w+(w>=0?2:-2)*Ka:w,S^p>=e^M>=e){var k=jt(zt(g),zt(n));Ft(k);var A=jt(i,k);Ft(A);var N=(S^w>=0?-1:1)*V(A[2]);r>N&&(c+=S^w>=0?1:-1)}if(!y++)break;p=M,d=b,v=_,g=n}Math.abs(u)>Qa&&(a=!0)}}return(!o&&!a&&0>Co||-Qa>u)^1&c}function Qt(n){var t,e=0/0,r=0/0,i=0/0;return{lineStart:function(){n.lineStart(),t=1},point:function(u,a){var o=u>0?Ka:-Ka,c=Math.abs(u-e);Math.abs(c-Ka)<Qa?(n.point(e,r=(r+a)/2>0?Ka/2:-Ka/2),n.point(i,r),n.lineEnd(),n.lineStart(),n.point(o,r),n.point(u,r),t=0):i!==o&&c>=Ka&&(Math.abs(e-i)<Qa&&(e-=i*Qa),Math.abs(u-o)<Qa&&(u-=o*Qa),r=ne(e,r,u,a),n.point(i,r),n.lineEnd(),n.lineStart(),n.point(o,r),t=0),n.point(e=u,r=a),i=o},lineEnd:function(){n.lineEnd(),e=r=0/0},clean:function(){return 2-t}}}function ne(n,t,e,r){var i,u,a=Math.sin(n-e);return Math.abs(a)>Qa?Math.atan((Math.sin(t)*(u=Math.cos(r))*Math.sin(e)-Math.sin(r)*(i=Math.cos(t))*Math.sin(n))/(i*u*a)):(t+r)/2}function te(n,t,e,r){var i;if(null==n)i=e*Ka/2,r.point(-Ka,i),r.point(0,i),r.point(Ka,i),r.point(Ka,0),r.point(Ka,-i),r.point(0,-i),r.point(-Ka,-i),r.point(-Ka,0),r.point(-Ka,i);else if(Math.abs(n[0]-t[0])>Qa){var u=(n[0]<t[0]?1:-1)*Ka;i=e*u/2,r.point(-u,i),r.point(0,i),r.point(u,i)}else r.point(t[0],t[1])}function ee(n){return Kt(Zo,n)}function re(n){function t(n,t){return Math.cos(n)*Math.cos(t)>a}function e(n){var e,u,a,c,s;return{lineStart:function(){c=a=!1,s=1},point:function(f,h){var g,p=[f,h],m=t(f,h),d=o?m?0:i(f,h):m?i(f+(0>f?Ka:-Ka),h):0;if(!e&&(c=a=m)&&n.lineStart(),m!==a&&(g=r(e,p),(Ot(e,g)||Ot(p,g))&&(p[0]+=Qa,p[1]+=Qa,m=t(p[0],p[1]))),m!==a)s=0,m?(n.lineStart(),g=r(p,e),n.point(g[0],g[1])):(g=r(e,p),n.point(g[0],g[1]),n.lineEnd()),e=g;else if(l&&e&&o^m){var v;d&u||!(v=r(p,e,!0))||(s=0,o?(n.lineStart(),n.point(v[0][0],v[0][1]),n.point(v[1][0],v[1][1]),n.lineEnd()):(n.point(v[1][0],v[1][1]),n.lineEnd(),n.lineStart(),n.point(v[0][0],v[0][1])))}!m||e&&Ot(e,p)||n.point(p[0],p[1]),e=p,a=m,u=d},lineEnd:function(){a&&n.lineEnd(),e=null},clean:function(){return s|(c&&a)<<1}}}function r(n,t,e){var r=zt(n),i=zt(t),u=[1,0,0],o=jt(r,i),c=Dt(o,o),l=o[0],s=c-l*l;if(!s)return!e&&n;var f=a*c/s,h=-a*l/s,g=jt(u,o),p=Ht(u,f),m=Ht(o,h);Lt(p,m);var d=g,v=Dt(p,d),y=Dt(d,d),M=v*v-y*(Dt(p,p)-1);if(!(0>M)){var x=Math.sqrt(M),b=Ht(d,(-v-x)/y);if(Lt(b,p),b=Pt(b),!e)return b;var _,w=n[0],S=t[0],E=n[1],k=t[1];w>S&&(_=w,w=S,S=_);var A=S-w,N=Math.abs(A-Ka)<Qa,q=N||Qa>A;if(!N&&E>k&&(_=E,E=k,k=_),q?N?E+k>0^b[1]<(Math.abs(b[0]-w)<Qa?E:k):E<=b[1]&&b[1]<=k:A>Ka^(w<=b[0]&&b[0]<=S)){var T=Ht(d,(-v+x)/y);return Lt(T,p),[b,Pt(T)]}}}function i(t,e){var r=o?n:Ka-n,i=0;return-r>t?i|=1:t>r&&(i|=2),-r>e?i|=4:e>r&&(i|=8),i}function u(n){return Kt(c,n)}var a=Math.cos(n),o=a>0,c=[n,0],l=Math.abs(a)>Qa,s=Ne(n,6*to);return $t(t,e,s,u)}function ie(n,t,e,r){function i(r,i){return Math.abs(r[0]-n)<Qa?i>0?0:3:Math.abs(r[0]-e)<Qa?i>0?2:1:Math.abs(r[1]-t)<Qa?i>0?1:0:i>0?3:2}function u(n,t){return a(n.point,t.point)}function a(n,t){var e=i(n,1),r=i(t,1);return e!==r?e-r:0===e?t[1]-n[1]:1===e?n[0]-t[0]:2===e?n[1]-t[1]:t[0]-n[0]}function o(i,u){var a=u[0]-i[0],o=u[1]-i[1],c=[0,1];return Math.abs(a)<Qa&&Math.abs(o)<Qa?n<=i[0]&&i[0]<=e&&t<=i[1]&&i[1]<=r:ue(n-i[0],a,c)&&ue(i[0]-e,-a,c)&&ue(t-i[1],o,c)&&ue(i[1]-r,-o,c)?(c[1]<1&&(u[0]=i[0]+c[1]*a,u[1]=i[1]+c[1]*o),c[0]>0&&(i[0]+=c[0]*a,i[1]+=c[0]*o),!0):!1}return function(c){function l(u){var a=i(u,-1),o=s([0===a||3===a?n:e,a>1?r:t]);return o}function s(n){for(var t=0,e=M.length,r=n[1],i=0;e>i;++i)for(var u,a=1,o=M[i],c=o.length,l=o[0];c>a;++a)u=o[a],l[1]<=r?u[1]>r&&f(l,u,n)>0&&++t:u[1]<=r&&f(l,u,n)<0&&--t,l=u;return 0!==t}function f(n,t,e){return(t[0]-n[0])*(e[1]-n[1])-(e[0]-n[0])*(t[1]-n[1])}function h(u,o,c,l){var s=0,f=0;if(null==u||(s=i(u,c))!==(f=i(o,c))||a(u,o)<0^c>0){do l.point(0===s||3===s?n:e,s>1?r:t);while((s=(s+c+4)%4)!==f)}else l.point(o[0],o[1])}function g(i,u){return i>=n&&e>=i&&u>=t&&r>=u}function p(n,t){g(n,t)&&c.point(n,t)}function m(){T.point=v,M&&M.push(x=[]),A=!0,k=!1,S=E=0/0}function d(){y&&(v(b,_),w&&k&&q.rejoin(),y.push(q.buffer())),T.point=p,k&&c.lineEnd()}function v(n,t){n=Math.max(-Bo,Math.min(Bo,n)),t=Math.max(-Bo,Math.min(Bo,t));var e=g(n,t);if(M&&x.push([n,t]),A)b=n,_=t,w=e,A=!1,e&&(c.lineStart(),c.point(n,t));else if(e&&k)c.point(n,t);else{var r=[S,E],i=[n,t];o(r,i)?(k||(c.lineStart(),c.point(r[0],r[1])),c.point(i[0],i[1]),e||c.lineEnd()):e&&(c.lineStart(),c.point(n,t))}S=n,E=t,k=e}var y,M,x,b,_,w,S,E,k,A,N=c,q=Jt(),T={point:p,lineStart:m,lineEnd:d,polygonStart:function(){c=q,y=[],M=[]},polygonEnd:function(){c=N,(y=ya.merge(y)).length?(c.polygonStart(),Zt(y,u,l,h,c),c.polygonEnd()):s([n,t])&&(c.polygonStart(),c.lineStart(),h(null,null,1,c),c.lineEnd(),c.polygonEnd()),y=M=x=null}};return T}}function ue(n,t,e){if(Math.abs(t)<Qa)return 0>=n;var r=n/t;if(t>0){if(r>e[1])return!1;r>e[0]&&(e[0]=r)}else{if(r<e[0])return!1;r<e[1]&&(e[1]=r)}return!0}function ae(n,t){function e(e,r){return e=n(e,r),t(e[0],e[1])}return n.invert&&t.invert&&(e.invert=function(e,r){return e=t.invert(e,r),e&&n.invert(e[0],e[1])}),e}function oe(n){var t=0,e=Ka/3,r=be(n),i=r(t,e);return i.parallels=function(n){return arguments.length?r(t=n[0]*Ka/180,e=n[1]*Ka/180):[180*(t/Ka),180*(e/Ka)]},i}function ce(n,t){function e(n,t){var e=Math.sqrt(u-2*i*Math.sin(t))/i;return[e*Math.sin(n*=i),a-e*Math.cos(n)]}var r=Math.sin(n),i=(r+Math.sin(t))/2,u=1+r*(2*i-r),a=Math.sqrt(u)/i;return e.invert=function(n,t){var e=a-t;return[Math.atan2(n,e)/i,V((u-(n*n+e*e)*i*i)/(2*i))]},e}function le(){function n(n,t){Wo+=i*n-r*t,r=n,i=t}var t,e,r,i;nc.point=function(u,a){nc.point=n,t=r=u,e=i=a},nc.lineEnd=function(){n(t,e)}}function se(n,t){Jo>n&&(Jo=n),n>Ko&&(Ko=n),Go>t&&(Go=t),t>Qo&&(Qo=t)}function fe(){function n(n,t){a.push("M",n,",",t,u)}function t(n,t){a.push("M",n,",",t),o.point=e}function e(n,t){a.push("L",n,",",t)}function r(){o.point=n}function i(){a.push("Z")}var u=he(4.5),a=[],o={point:n,lineStart:function(){o.point=t},lineEnd:r,polygonStart:function(){o.lineEnd=i},polygonEnd:function(){o.lineEnd=r,o.point=n},pointRadius:function(n){return u=he(n),o},result:function(){if(a.length){var n=a.join("");return a=[],n}}};return o}function he(n){return"m0,"+n+"a"+n+","+n+" 0 1,1 0,"+-2*n+"a"+n+","+n+" 0 1,1 0,"+2*n+"z"}function ge(n,t){Lo+=n,Ho+=t,++Fo}function pe(){function n(n,r){var i=n-t,u=r-e,a=Math.sqrt(i*i+u*u);Po+=a*(t+n)/2,Oo+=a*(e+r)/2,Yo+=a,ge(t=n,e=r)}var t,e;ec.point=function(r,i){ec.point=n,ge(t=r,e=i)}}function me(){ec.point=ge}function de(){function n(n,t){var e=n-r,u=t-i,a=Math.sqrt(e*e+u*u);Po+=a*(r+n)/2,Oo+=a*(i+t)/2,Yo+=a,a=i*n-r*t,Ro+=a*(r+n),Uo+=a*(i+t),Io+=3*a,ge(r=n,i=t)}var t,e,r,i;ec.point=function(u,a){ec.point=n,ge(t=r=u,e=i=a)},ec.lineEnd=function(){n(t,e)}}function ve(n){function t(t,e){n.moveTo(t,e),n.arc(t,e,a,0,2*Ka)}function e(t,e){n.moveTo(t,e),o.point=r}function r(t,e){n.lineTo(t,e)}function i(){o.point=t}function u(){n.closePath()}var a=4.5,o={point:t,lineStart:function(){o.point=e},lineEnd:i,polygonStart:function(){o.lineEnd=u},polygonEnd:function(){o.lineEnd=i,o.point=t},pointRadius:function(n){return a=n,o},result:s};return o}function ye(n){function t(t){function r(e,r){e=n(e,r),t.point(e[0],e[1])}function i(){M=0/0,S.point=a,t.lineStart()}function a(r,i){var a=zt([r,i]),o=n(r,i);e(M,x,y,b,_,w,M=o[0],x=o[1],y=r,b=a[0],_=a[1],w=a[2],u,t),t.point(M,x)}function o(){S.point=r,t.lineEnd()}function c(){i(),S.point=l,S.lineEnd=s}function l(n,t){a(f=n,h=t),g=M,p=x,m=b,d=_,v=w,S.point=a}function s(){e(M,x,y,b,_,w,g,p,f,m,d,v,u,t),S.lineEnd=o,o()}var f,h,g,p,m,d,v,y,M,x,b,_,w,S={point:r,lineStart:i,lineEnd:o,polygonStart:function(){t.polygonStart(),S.lineStart=c},polygonEnd:function(){t.polygonEnd(),S.lineStart=i}};return S}function e(t,u,a,o,c,l,s,f,h,g,p,m,d,v){var y=s-t,M=f-u,x=y*y+M*M;if(x>4*r&&d--){var b=o+g,_=c+p,w=l+m,S=Math.sqrt(b*b+_*_+w*w),E=Math.asin(w/=S),k=Math.abs(Math.abs(w)-1)<Qa?(a+h)/2:Math.atan2(_,b),A=n(k,E),N=A[0],q=A[1],T=N-t,C=q-u,z=M*T-y*C;(z*z/x>r||Math.abs((y*T+M*C)/x-.5)>.3||i>o*g+c*p+l*m)&&(e(t,u,a,o,c,l,N,q,k,b/=S,_/=S,w,d,v),v.point(N,q),e(N,q,k,b,_,w,s,f,h,g,p,m,d,v))}}var r=.5,i=Math.cos(30*to),u=16;return t.precision=function(n){return arguments.length?(u=(r=n*n)>0&&16,t):Math.sqrt(r)},t}function Me(n){var t=ye(function(t,e){return n([t*eo,e*eo])});return function(n){return n=t(n),{point:function(t,e){n.point(t*to,e*to)},sphere:function(){n.sphere()},lineStart:function(){n.lineStart()},lineEnd:function(){n.lineEnd()},polygonStart:function(){n.polygonStart()},polygonEnd:function(){n.polygonEnd()}}}}function xe(n){return be(function(){return n})()}function be(n){function t(n){return n=o(n[0]*to,n[1]*to),[n[0]*h+c,l-n[1]*h]}function e(n){return n=o.invert((n[0]-c)/h,(l-n[1])/h),n&&[n[0]*eo,n[1]*eo]}function r(){o=ae(a=Se(v,y,M),u);var n=u(m,d);return c=g-n[0]*h,l=p+n[1]*h,i()}function i(){return s&&(s.valid=!1,s=null),t}var u,a,o,c,l,s,f=ye(function(n,t){return n=u(n,t),[n[0]*h+c,l-n[1]*h]}),h=150,g=480,p=250,m=0,d=0,v=0,y=0,M=0,x=Xo,b=mt,_=null,w=null;return t.stream=function(n){return s&&(s.valid=!1),s=_e(a,x(f(b(n)))),s.valid=!0,s},t.clipAngle=function(n){return arguments.length?(x=null==n?(_=n,Xo):re((_=+n)*to),i()):_},t.clipExtent=function(n){return arguments.length?(w=n,b=null==n?mt:ie(n[0][0],n[0][1],n[1][0],n[1][1]),i()):w},t.scale=function(n){return arguments.length?(h=+n,r()):h},t.translate=function(n){return arguments.length?(g=+n[0],p=+n[1],r()):[g,p]},t.center=function(n){return arguments.length?(m=n[0]%360*to,d=n[1]%360*to,r()):[m*eo,d*eo]},t.rotate=function(n){return arguments.length?(v=n[0]%360*to,y=n[1]%360*to,M=n.length>2?n[2]%360*to:0,r()):[v*eo,y*eo,M*eo]},ya.rebind(t,f,"precision"),function(){return u=n.apply(this,arguments),t.invert=u.invert&&e,r()}}function _e(n,t){return{point:function(e,r){r=n(e*to,r*to),e=r[0],t.point(e>Ka?e-2*Ka:-Ka>e?e+2*Ka:e,r[1])},sphere:function(){t.sphere()},lineStart:function(){t.lineStart()},lineEnd:function(){t.lineEnd()},polygonStart:function(){t.polygonStart()},polygonEnd:
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any D3 release, `d3.version` gives you the version loaded, whether it is minified or not.

For instance, using D3 v3.3.0:

```js
console.log(d3.version)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

That works even for very old releases, like D3 v1.2:

```js
console.log(d3.version)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/1.29.5/d3.min.js"></script>
```