# How to check D3 version?

Tags: d3.js, version

This question is not an exact duplicate, it is a "translation hub" for non-obvious questions:

- About **core version**: this question is about "How to check at runtime", but there are good answer at   [this other question: *"How to find the exact version of D3 given the minified file?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55286560/287948).
- About **module version**: "D3 is a collection of modules" (see [official D3 API documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md)), *module* is the correct term, but you can use [this question: *"How to find out about loaded d3.js extensions and their versions at runtime?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55646133/287948).

---

There is a property **like `d3.version`** for "core version"? or some "per module" property or method to check version?   (imagining for example something like `d3.csv.version`)

The [API docs](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md) show nothing about it.

PS: supposing that it is stable and can be checked for example in embedded D3 like `Plotly.d3`.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado please check edits

Comment: Since you already accepted an answer, there will be no difference in opening it or not. However, as I'm too tired to argue that it's a duplicate, I'll reopen it. By the way, you have no downvote, not a single one, so I'm not sure why you said *"EDIT after downvotes"*.

Comment: Thanks @GerardoFurtado and @ altocumulus, I remember to see a vote :-)  but I edited again (removing comment about downvoted)

Comment: @PeterKrauss The edit is still not good: the question is open now, so it makes no sense talking about duplicates, the users will be confused.. Have in mind that the whole point of these Q&A is having a reference for future users. That being said, edit your question to the best description of the problem and, after that, I'll flag all these comments as *"no longer needed"*.

Comment: Hi @GerardoFurtado and Downvoter:  the question is duplicated on my opinion... How to formalize "sorry it is a duplicate", there are no template or **mark** to say it to the SO robot?  PS: my edits will be preserved, they are  about "How bad are the questions" that are links to the solution.

Comment: I already had closed it as a duplicate, and you asked me to reopen it. I cannot close it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update (2023-10-19):

As of `d3@>7.0.0`, the version number is no longer exposed. The last version that had it was `d3@6.7.0`.

---

### Old response:

You're correct, you can figure out the version using `d3.version`.

Just checked using `console.log(d3)` to see all the methods and properties available, and `version` was listed.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3e42bxom/2/

Comment: Oops, sorry, I not tested ;-)

Comment: And about modules, like `d3.csv`, some clue?

Comment: I don't think you can see the version if you are only using the standalone versions. The `version` is no longer included in the `d3` object. For example, I added the `d3-fetch` and `d3-shape` standalone libraries, and I saw functions from both but doesn't mention the version.

Comment: Thanks @altocumulus, I edited the question adding your link, check if the edited question is ok

Comment: @leocreatini  thanks. well, I checked `Plotly.d3.version`  and it is fine (Ploty is using D3 v3, ugh!)

Comment: The d3 object no longer has a version field

Answer (score 1):

Go to the browser console where your D3-based site is loaded. From there, the following will print the loaded version of d3 in the browser:

```
var d3version = require("d3")
d3version.version
```